# Docker no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

the following docker container was created on MAC but when i am trying to run it on windows it is giving following error. On windows I am using docker tools as i am running on Windows 10 home but other containers are running successfully

```
Creating network "server_default" with the default driver
Creating server_db_1      ... done
Creating server_adminer_1 ... done
Creating server_app_1     ... done
Attaching to server_db_1, server_adminer_1, server_app_1
db_1       | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-03-20 06:57:10 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1       | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
app_1      | npm ERR! code ENOENT
app_1      | npm ERR! syscall open
app_1      | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
app_1      | npm ERR! errno -2
app_1      | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
app_1      | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
app_1      | npm ERR! enoent
app_1      |
app_1      | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app_1      | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-20T11_02_58_067Z-debug.log
server_app_1 exited with code 254
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    # image: postgres
    build:
      context: ./docker/db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8080

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./:/app
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR "/app"

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

the docker is running succesfully on MAC OS but not able to run on windows

Comment: Bind-mounting `volumes:` over your application code nullifies most of the work that's done in the Dockerfile, and can lead to system-specific problems like this.  It also tells Docker to ignore any change to your `package.json` file which can cause problems.  Does deleting the `app` `volumes:` help things?

Comment: @DavidMaze deleting `volume` does help the docker is running but is not giving expected output 

i am getting the following log 

`db_1       | LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-03-20 11:15:55 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
db_1       | LOG:  invalid record length at 0/235C520: wanted 24, got 0`